# schedule a task after a delay in executor service

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I want a task to be executed after a delay of 3 seconds and my one task takes  2 seconds to finish.

The output i am getting is showing interval of 5 seconds

**Note**:The Student class implements Callable interface
**I have the following queries**

1. Why there is delay of 5 seconds coming.How can make a delay of 3
   seconds Why are thread 1 is showed in second execution ,it should be
   thread two

The output i am getting is

```
The time is : Sat Nov 26 15:08:02 IST 2016

Doing a task during : prerna - Time - Sat Nov 26 15:08:06 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-1 Helloprerna
Doing a task during : abc - Time - Sat Nov 26 15:08:11 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-1 Helloabc
Doing a task during : def - Time - Sat Nov 26 15:08:16 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-2 Hellodef
Doing a task during : xyz - Time - Sat Nov 26 15:08:21 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-1 Helloxyz
Doing a task during : ritu - Time - Sat Nov 26 15:08:26 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-3 Helloritu
Doing a task during : babita - Time - Sat Nov 26 15:08:31 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-2 Hellobabita
```

The code:

```
private String display(String name2) {

    try {
        //  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        name2=Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Hello"+ name;
        System.out.println("Doing a task during : " + name + " - Time - " + new Date());
        Thread.sleep(000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name2;
}


@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (name == "archana") {

        throw new Exception();
    }
        /*} catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            return "error";
        }*/

    return display(name);
}

public class ExecutorScheduleDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
        ScheduledExecutorService executor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

        list.add(new Student("prerna"));
        list.add(new Student("abc"));
        //list.add(new Student("archana"));
        list.add(new Student("def"));
        list.add(new Student("xyz"));
        list.add(new Student("ritu"));
        list.add(new Student("babita"));
        System.out.println("The time is : " + new Date());
        List<Future<String>> resultList= new  ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        for(Student s:list){
            Future<String> f=executor.schedule(s, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            try {
                System.out.println(f.get());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? it is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete eeedev's answer, since your object seems to be a `Callable`:

You can simply create a new `FutureTask` by passing your `Callable` to the constructor, as described in the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)

Note that the FutureTask's type parameter must be the same as the Callable's.

Example:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        FutureTask<String> fooFutureTask = new FutureTask<>(foo);
    }
}

class Foo implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Calling";
    }
}
```

You can then schedule your newly created `FutureTask` for execution as described by eeedev.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed now. There was a trailing slash in the link

Answer (score 5):

Use [`scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit timeunit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) instead of `schedule(Runnable task, long delay, TimeUnit timeunit)`.

> `scheduleAtFixedRate (Runnable, long initialDelay, long period,
>   TimeUnit timeunit)`
>   Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period; that is executions will commence after `initialDelay` then `initialDelay+period`, then `initialDelay + 2 * period`, and so on. If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor. If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.
>   next execution.

Comment: mine is callable type not runnable I am returning values

Comment: @coder25 then wrap your callables in a [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), which can be scheduled because it's a `Runnable`.

Comment: i didnt get you how to wrap  callable in future   task